# what does salt mean public-routable IP and private-routable IP?

Tags: routes, salt-stack

i have read the quickstart about saltstack, however the explanation about salt-minion id value confused me in "public-routable" and "private-routable" IP.

Does it mean that **public-routable** ip address is something like 202.*.*.* other than 127.*.*.*, 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.*.

Is assumption above correct?

Answer (score 0):

after Googling, it comes to me that the above assumption is correct. according to the [page](http://usatcorp.com/faqs/can-determine-publicly-routable-ip-address/), private-routable IP address region is below:

- 10.0.0.0 through 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 through 172.32.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255